# QStringList generating Username from String

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a simple program that Takes a Full Name entered by the user for Example "Peter Mills" and generates a Username From the First Letter of the First Name and the first 4 digits of the Last Name?

SO Output should be "pmill"

How on earth do i do this. Im still very new with Qt Please can someone shed some light on this for me. This is what i have at this stage

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include<QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cin(stdin);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    QString fullName;

    cout << "Enter Your Full Name: " << endl;
    cin >> fullName;

    QStringList username = fullName.split(" ");
    username[0]=username[0][1];

    QString usernameJoin = username.join("");
    cout << "Full name is : " << fullName << endl;
    cout << "Username is : " << usernameJoin << endl;





    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: QString result = username[0].left(1)+username[1].left(4);. Assuming that there are no spaces in the first and last names, and that both are long enough (do the error checking).

Comment: I do not need to do error checking for this assignment.  If i run this I only get the second letter of the first name?

Comment: Well, cin stops at word boundaries so you're actually reading only the first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on your code that will do what you want :

```
QTextStream cin(stdin);
QTextStream cout(stdout);

QString firstName, lastName;

cout << "Enter Your Full Name: " << endl;
cin >> firstName >> lastName;

QString userName = (firstName.left(1)+lastName.left(4)).toLower();

cout << "Full name is : " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << endl;
cout << "Username is : " << userName << endl;
```

`cin` stops at word boundaries, so you have to read the first and last names in two times.

Then you can use `QString::left(int n)` to get the n leftmost characters of a QString, and `QString::toLower()` to convert the result to lowercase.

This is exactly what we use above, we take the 1 first characters of the first name, the 4 first characters of the last name, put them together, and convert the result to lowercase.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this, if I use QInputDialog?  Will I be able to do it without prompting first and last name seperate?

Comment: @Vaaljan if you use QInputDialog, then you'll get a single QString, let's call it `input` and you can do the same thing with `firstName =input.split(" ")[0]` and `lastName = input.split(" ")[1]`